# Connect Microsoft Powerapps to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, powerapps, powerapps-datatable

I'm trying to connect a PowerApps application to my database in PostgreSQL but it won'tt let me, the error it gives me is:

```
PostgreSQL: We were unable to find a database provider with invariant name 'Npgsql'.
```

I have installed a gateway.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the npgsql driver from 
- https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases - probably you need to check install into GAC during installation

Then follow this guide:
[PowerApps PostgreSQL SSL problem](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/The-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation/td-p/531475)